# Services in /etc/rc.local prevent the system from finishing to boot

Tags: startup

I start some services such as Tomcat and MySQL from a shell script `/etc/rc.local`. There is a while loop to restart the services. This loop is continuously running and my system is not booting. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to exit from rc.local to continue booting. Put an ampersand (`&`) after your command in the `rc.local` file, that should help.